How do you solve Euler's Equation of Motion for time-varying Moments?
I'm trying to simulate a 3DOF inverted pendulum (See my other post for details). My inverted pendulum will have moments imparted onto it for short durations at a time from cold gas thrusters sitting at the head of the pendulum. If I have an expression for the moments on the pendulum at some time, how can I solve for the current angular velocity?
In my other post, I do mention trying to numerically integrate the equation $\sum \vec{M} = \frac{d \vec{L}}{dt}$ for $\vec{L}$ and then solving for $\vec{\omega}$ via the equation $\vec{L} = I \vec{\omega}$.
I did also come across Euler's equation of motion-- $I \dot{\vec{\omega}}+\vec{\omega} \times(I \vec{\omega}) = \vec{M}$.
So my question is which method should I do? Is one better than the other? If I should go with Euler's Equations of motions, I don't even know where to begin to try to solve that non-linear coupled system of differential equations.
